# Making a questionnaire with Qt, using QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qscrollarea

I'm trying to make a questionnaire with Qt, using Qt Designer to design the forms.

I want to display each question and the possible answers on a line, one question under the previous one. The problem is that I've got too many question to fit in my window.

I tried using qtscrollarea but I can't manage to get the scroll bars....

I am using QtDesigner, I put a qtscrollarea, with a vertical layout in it, adding the QWidgets containing question and answers in the vertical layout. I tried to force the vertical layout to be bigger than the qtscrollarea, tried to change somme Qwidget to horiontal layout, taking off the vertical layout... But still no way to have a scroll bar.

Any advice on a way of doing it through QtDesigner?

Comment: You write that scroll bars are missing, but what happens more exactly? Is the form still visible, but the you would like to shrink the size of the form so that scrolling is needed or has it stopped working altogether, i.e. no form is visible? Code would be helpful.

Comment: Use YourScrollArea->widget()->layout() as the layout your child-widgets are placed on and YourScrollArea->widget() as parent. Set YourScrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true). As soon as your child-widgets reach the borders a scrollbar should be shown.

Comment: @user2672165 : Well... As I said it, I'm using QtDesigner, which means I don't have any Code written by myself to hadle the GUI. The questions appear in the scrollarea, but the parts that exceed the size of the scrollarea are hidden, and no scroll bar are displayed.

Comment: @Sebastian Lange : this seems promising, but is there a way of doing it with Qtdesigner ? I can't find how to set the layout of my qtsrollarea

Comment: Add a widget in the layout and then select the layout

Comment: @Tonial What type of QWidget do you use to display answers/questions? Or how do you display answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

place a qtscrollarea

place in qtscrollarea widgets containing question and answers

right click on qtscrollarea and select layout, vertical in your case

Comment: Isn't it QScrollArea ?